# Calling custom android app from a google chrome browser

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser

I have an android app and I want to open it whenever user tries to access a particular page from the chrome browser in phone.

the link from which I want to try opening from chrome to open the app is
Link: https://www.privlyalpha.org/

---

My manifest.xml is like this.I have applied some changes but nothing seems to work.Please don't refer to any earlier post as I have already tried many

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="ly.priv.mobile"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.0.0.1">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/customPrivlyTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".gui.activities.LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="privlyalpha.org"
                    android:pathPrefix="pages/privacy"
                    />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".gui.activities.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="privlyT4JCallback"
                    android:scheme="oauth" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".gui.activities.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/settings"
            android:parentActivityName=".gui.activities.MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".gui.activities.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your host and scheme, make your link action into ,

```
<a href="https://privlyalpha.org">click here</a>
```

on the page that opens once navigate to above mentioned url.